# How can I use both props and posts at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code for the display of profile details. I just want to know whether can I use props and posts at the same time?

If yes, is it correct the way I have used?

[image: code screenshot]

**This is my full code** - And I get the error saying
"Failed to compile.

./src/components/Profile.js
Line 91:  'posts' is not defined  no-undef"

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";
import spinner from "../spinner.gif";




const Profile = props => {

  const [profile, setProfile] = useState([]);

const [First_Name, setFirstName] = useState("");
const [Last_Name, setLastName] = useState("");
const [Birthday, setBirthday] = useState("");
const [Gender, setGender] = useState("");
const [City, setCity] = useState("");
const [Country, setCountry] = useState("");
const [Contact_No, setContactNo] = useState("");
const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
const [Available_Day, setAvailableDay] = useState("");
const [Available_Date, setAvailableDate] = useState("");
const [Available_STime, setStartTime] = useState("");
const [Available_ETime, setEndTime] = useState("");


//Delete Profile by Id
const deleteProfile = id => {
  axios.delete(`/profiles/${id}`)
  .then(res => alert(res.data))
  setProfile(profile.filter(elem => elem._id !== id));
}



useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/profiles/${props.match.params.id}`)
    .then(res => [
        setFirstName(res.data.First_Name),
        setLastName(res.data.Last_Name),
        setBirthday(res.data.Birthday),
        setGender(res.data.Gender),
        setCity(res.data.City),
        setCountry(res.data.Country),
        setContactNo(res.data.Contact_No),
        setFileName(res.data.profileImage),
        setAvailableDay(res.data.Available_Day),
        setAvailableDate(res.data.Available_Date),
        setStartTime(res.data.Available_STime),
        setEndTime(res.data.Available_ETime)
    ])
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}, [props]);



  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <img src={`/uploads/${fileName}`} alt="..." style={{
        margin: "0 auto",
        width: "50%",
        display: "flex"
      }}/>
      
      <br></br><br></br>
      
        {!First_Name || !Last_Name || !Birthday || !Gender || !City || !Country || !Contact_No || !Available_Day || !Available_Date || !Available_STime || !Available_ETime ? (<img src = {spinner} alt="loading..."/>
         ) : (
        <> 
        <h2>Dr. {First_Name} {Last_Name}</h2><br></br>
        <h3>Date of Birthday  : {Birthday}</h3><br></br>
        <h3>Gender            : {Gender}</h3><br></br>
        <h3>City              : {City}</h3><br></br>
        <h3>Country           : {Country}</h3><br></br>
        <h3>Contact Number    : {Contact_No}</h3><br></br>
        <hr></hr>
        <h3>Available on {Available_Day} - {Available_Date}</h3>
        <h3>From {Available_STime} a.m. to {Available_ETime} p.m. </h3><br></br>
       
        <br/>
        <Link to="/" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Back
            </Link ><br></br><br></br>

           
       </>

         )}

        {( posts.map((profile) => (
            
            <div className="row my-5">

            <div className="col-sm-2">
              <Link to={`/update/${profile._id}`} className="btn btn-outline-success">Edit Profile</Link>
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-2">
              <button onClick={() => deleteProfile (profile._id)} className="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete Profile</button>
            </div>

          </div>
       

        )))}

    </MainContainer>
  );
};



export default Profile;

//Main Container
const MainContainer = styled.div`
    margin: 6rem auto;
    padding: 3rem 14rem;

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        front-weight: 900;
        color: var(--dark-green)
    }


    img {
        width: 10rem;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .btn-primary {
        background: var(--dark-green);
        border:none;
        &:hover {
          background: var(--light-green);
        }
      }

`;
```

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: If this is a react component, then your function only get passed in one argument: the props object. If there's a posts props it will be part of that object, not a second parameter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited now. Sorry for that!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you call your profile like in this example:

```
return (
  <Profile picture={picture} posts={posts}>{name}</Profile>
)
```

Then you would have an equivalent component accepting the props as follows:

```
const Profile = ({ posts, picture, children }) => {}
```

Whereas the `posts` and `picture` are what you have referred to when calling the component and the children is the `name` in our small example.

A longer and more detailed guide for the ongoing journey can be found over here: [ReactJS - Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: I have tried "const Profile = ({posts, props}) => // " and then I get the error "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","  "

Comment: Well, you don't need to put the double slashes at the end. So just, `const Profile = ({posts, name, picture }) => {`. 

And additionally to that, props contains the passed information, i.e: `props.picture`. But if you write `({ posts })`, then you have taken `posts` from `props`.

Answer (score 0):

once argument is destructured in the function,they will automatically becomes props.
No need to write props.post just do:

```
const myFunct = ({post}) => {
//
//
// 
}
```

Now you can access any key value pairs within post just by writting post.keyName